# Creating an android custom view instead of multiple views with different data

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 5 different views created in java classes. They consists of constructers, an init method which all constructers calls and then an onDraw method which draws a graph.

In each view, the init method and onDraw are loaded with different data as the graphs are not the same. But the init and onDraw is basically the same.

Can I create one custom view that could be reused instead?

Also in the views, there is a textview for each view. The textview are also very similiar, else than the data loaded into it in its java class, so is it also possible to create a custom
textview, used by the custom view? All the examples I have seen use a custom textview, doesn't have any difference in which data is being loaded and I have to determine which view is calling,
so that the right data is loaded.

Here are the example of the layout (With one 2 views included to simplify, also its cleaned from the unnecessary layout specific stuff):

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <com.company.views.FirstView
        android:id="@+id/firstView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.company.views.FirstTextView
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <com.company.views.SecondView
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.company.views.SecondTextView
        android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</TableRow>
```

Here are the example of one of the views (also scraped):

```
public class FirstView extends View {
  Paint paint;
  int y = 0;

  public FirstView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
  }

  private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        paint = com.company.helpers.Drawing.LineStyle("#00FF00", screenResolution.lineThickness); // <- the color is one of the differences for each view
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    y=GraphType.SpecificGraphType; // <- this is one of the other differences for each view

    // drawing part is irrelevant

    invalidate();
  }
}
```

Here are the example of one of the textviews:

```
public class FirstTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    private string defaultText;

    public FirstTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public FirstTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public FirstTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
        defaultText=Model.getInstance().SpecificGraphType; // <- this is one of the differences for each textview
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out its acually working as it should but I had an minnor code mistake in a override of setText(). So if anybody whats to share a view, you can look at my example above.

Answer (score 1):

Since your custom views extend TextView, there is no need to do findViewById. Your object itself is already the view.

So you can simply in your init() call setText("even awesomer");

Your code breaks, because findViewById returns null and then you get a NPE trying to call setText() on that.

To differentiate between Views within the View, just use getId().

```
private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
if (getId() == R.id.firstTextView) {
    ...
} else if (getId() == R.id.secondTextView) {
    ...
}
...
}
```